# prevent mongoDB shell errors on my production environment

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

how to prevent these error form mongoDB shell or when I try to connect to it from php

```
Message: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Remote server has closed the connection 

JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112 exception: connect failed

couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js
```

every time one of these error appear and i each time I have to run this commands

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock   
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair 
sudo service mongodb start
```

how to prevent and solve these error for ever at lease on my production environment.

Thanks

Comment: why the hell are you connecting mongo shell to php???

Comment: I connect to mongoDB  not to shell using php, but I use shell to do some queries

Comment: It seems like the service `mongodb` may be crashing? Have you looked at any of the logs?